# Encoding - Efficiently send sparse boolean array

Tags: optimization, encoding

I have a 256 x 256 boolean array. These array is constantly changing and set bits are practically randomly distributed.

I need to send a current list of the set bits to many clients as they request them.

Following numbers are approximations.

If I send the coordinates for each set bit:

```
set bits    data transfer (bytes)
    0            0
  100          200
  300          600
  500         1000
 1000         2000
```

If I send the distance (scanning from left to right) to the next set bit:

```
set bits    data transfer (bytes)
   0             0
  100          256
  300          300
  500          500
 1000         1000
```

The typical number of bits that are set in this sparse array is around 300-500, so the second solution is better.

Is there a way I can do better than this without much added processing overhead?

Comment: Have you tried any of the standard compression algorithms?

Comment: No, can you recommend one that's better than above?

Comment: Not of the top off my head. I'd just try a few common ones like gzip and see if there appears to be a sweet spot where your data gets compressed.

Comment: I would go with your second method. It's called run-coding. I suppose in principle you could [*Huffman-code*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) the run lengths.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on run-coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say "practically randomly distributed", let's assume that each location is a Bernoulli trial with probability p.  p is chosen to get the fill rate you expect.  You can think of the length of a "run" (your option 2) as the number of Bernoulli trials necessary to get a success.  It turns out this number of trials follows the Geometric distribution (with probability p).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

What you've done so far in option #2 is to recognize the maximum length of the run in each case of p, and reserve that many bits to send all of them.  Note that this maximum length is still just a probability, and the scheme will fail if you get REALLY REALLY unlucky, and all your bits are clustered at the beginning and end.

As @Mike Dunlavey recommends in the comment, Huffman coding, or some other form of entropy coding, can redistribute the bits spent according to the frequency of the length.  That is, short runs are much more common, so use fewer bits to send those lengths.  The theoretical limit for this encoding efficiency is the "entropy" of the distribution, which you can look up on that Wikipedia page, and evaluate for different probabilities.  In your case, this entropy ranges from 7.5 bits per run (for 1000 entries) to 10.8 bits per run (for 100).

Actually, this means you can't do much better than you're currently doing for the 1000 entry case.  8 bits = 1 byte per value.  For the case of 100 entries, you're currently spending 20.5 bits per run instead of the theoretically possible 10.8, so that end has the highest chance for improvement.  And in the case of 300: I think you haven't reserved enough bits to represent these sequences.  The entropy comes out to 9.23 bits per pixel, and you're currently sending 8.  You will find many cases where the space between true exceeds 256, which will overflow your representation.

All of this, of course, assumes that things really are random.  If they're not, you need a different entropy calculation.  You can always compute the entropy right out of your data with a histogram, and decide if it's worth pursuing a more complicated option.

Finally, also note that real-life entropy coders only approximate the entropy.  [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), for example, has to assign an integer number of bits to each run length.  [Arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) can assign fractional bits.